# Answer Highlight/Fade-out doesn't fade-out

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, user-interface

Frequently when following a direct link to an answer, the answer will stay highlighted indefinitely instead of fading-out like it supposed to.  This happens more often then not and gets very annoying.  There are no errors or warning in the javascript console or firebug, so I'm not sure what could be causing it.  Here's a [screencast of it](http://screencast.com/t/rszCe77ILnK).  This is happening in Firefox 3.5.

I'm wondering if this might be a firefox bug, because it stopped doing it for ~20 minutes after a restart.

Comment: This happens to me all the time on Safari (version 4.0.1, but it's happened on other browsers as well)

Comment: i had been seeing this and assumed it was because i had firebug turned on.  i experimented with turning it off and that seemed to fix it, but maybe i just got lucky...

Comment: Still broken for me in Chrome on Windows XP. See my comment in the accepted answer for bandage-fix suggestion.

Comment: Same as Kyle - broken in Safari.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've narrowed this issue down to the jQuery color animation plugin - it was way out of date.

The next build will incorporate the latest [jQuery.UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/); I haven't been able to repro any longer on our development sites!

#### Update

All sites now have this code live and I'm not able to repro a stuck background color.

Comment: +1 I know this happened to me quite often... Many times I wondered if the background was even supposed to fade. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: It just happened to me in Chrome. In fact, I added what must be a dupe question just now. I'll keep an eye on it and see if it goes away tomorrow.

Comment: @Nosredna - did it happen on this site?

Comment: No, it happened on SO.

Comment: ARRGG!  I can repro in Safari on Windows still :(

Comment: On SO, it's still happening in Chrome (Windows XP). Has the change been rolled out into SO yet?

Comment: What if you do a setInterval and check once every second to see if it exists before you animate it? Then see if people still have the problem. Obviously not an ideal solution, but just as a sanity check.

Comment: I'm starting to thing *you're* the problem here Nosredna. A little fishy that it's only affecting you, isn't it??

Comment: Well, everyone has always known _I'm_ a problem.

Comment: I wonder if the animate is happening or not. Could you pop it to white at the end of the animate? Then if we saw a pop or not, that'd at least be another clue.

Comment: Hey wait. Are you hinting that you have an 'if (user=="Nosredna") {screwrandomestuffup()}' condition on your server?

Comment: @Nosredna - that's exactly what I have on dev right now; at the end of the animation, ensure the background-color is the intended color.  I guess I should file a bug with jQuery.UI on this - the animate is called, but sometimes doesn't affect the color!

Comment: Yeah, you should file a bug. Get the jQuery mob looking at it. Good for everyone if it gets fixed.

Comment: I just saw the color "pop." You must have pushed that out to SO. Good work--that's much better than the permanent hang on the orange.

Comment: @Nosredna - yeah, that issue was a real pain!

Comment: In Safari (4) it's still broken for me.

Comment: @Isaac, does it hang on orange or pop to white?

Answer (score 3):

Did the whole of the page finish loading properly? I've noticed that it only starts fading out when it's loaded everything including the quantserve tracker and the jobs bit. If one of those got "stuck" for you, that could explain it.

Comment: Yes I have.  I even checked the headers and every request was returned with a 304 Not Modified or 200 OK status code.

Comment: Interesting. I basically only use Chrome, and I don't think I've *ever* seen it.

Comment: @Jon: Have you tried Chrome on Linux. The new tab page is enhanced and cooler (I guess because it's open source).

Comment: @Lucas: Yes, I use Chrome on Linux the whole time at work :)

Comment: I use Chrome-W and happened to me, but possibly because the reasons Jon described.

Comment: I use Chrome (almost) exclusively as well and have only seen it on meta and (I think) superuser.  Never noticed it on SO.

Comment: I use Chrome on Windows and I see it very often on SO. At least twice a day. It definitely hits Chrome.